# Laravel shows me an incorrect message [Is confuse]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-query-builder

Laravel error page shows me an incorrect error message, the messages says:

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'`

[image]

But I don't have a column id with the name "`id`" the correct name is  `id_doctor`.
I have correctly written the SQL Query (Query Builder), but Laravel thinks it's wrong.

This is my code, the function.

```
 public function editarMedico(Medicos $medicos){

    $datos = DB::table('medicos')
    ->join('tipo_medico','medicos.especialidad_id','=','tipo_medico.id_tipo_medico')
    ->selectRaw("medicos.id_doctor, CONCAT(medicos.nombre,' ',medicos.apellidos) AS nombre_medico, rut, fecha_nacimiento, tipo_medico.nombre_tipo AS especialidad, estado")
    ->where('medicos.id_doctor', '=' ,$medicos->id_doctor)->first();

    return view('forms.editar-horarios', compact('datos','medicos'));
    
}
```

I have already tried the following commands, I think it should be an error from the session.

First:

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject> [ctrl+c, to close batch connection] Do you want to close the connection (S/N)?
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject> [ctrl+c, to close serve connection]
```

Then:

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject> php artisan route:clear
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject> php artisan view:clear
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject> php artisan cache:clear
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject> php artisan config:clear

PS C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject>php artisan serve
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject>npm run dev
```

Then I close and open the connection from Xampp and I remove the project folder from Sublime Text and re-add. But nothing changed.

This is the route.

```
Route::get('/secretaria/editar/medicos/{medicos}', [MedicosController::class, 'editarMedico'])->name('horarios.editar');
```

If I change `editarMedico` to `edit` then the error says.

```
Method App\Http\Controllers\Medicos\MedicosController::edit does not exist.
```

That function is the cause of the problem. Laravel shows me a wrong view error. And If the function `editarMedico` was empty the error message doesn't change.

Additional, *How can I trace the error message, trace the precise route or controller?*

I don't know why Laravel show me an incorrect error. What Can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use model binding like this.

```
public function editarMedico(Medicos $medicos) {
```

It will automatically fetch the model based on its properties in the model class, in the database. Since you have not specified it `Laravel` believes that the primary key is `id`.

To fix it, in the class `Medicos.php`. Set you primary key to be the correct one.

```
class Medico extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_doctor';
}
```

Comment: OK now it's works, but why now? Laravel has never given me those kind of errors before. I have programmed in this way before and Laravel does not give errors like that, could it be because I moved the controller to another folder? Because I don't think so, I believe in your explanation.

Comment: If your model binding was not working before that could have been a case where it would not crash etc. but in general you have to define primary keys if they are not using id as the column name, no matter where the files are located :)